mach_task_self_ is not concurrency-safe because it involves shared mutable state
I have a function that returns the memory use of a device. It uses mach_task_self_ which gives a warning that it is not concurrency-safe.
task_info(mach_task_self_, task_flavor_t(TASK_VM_INFO), intPtr, &count)

According to this answer you can import and mark as @preconcurrency however when I try this it doesn't work.
@preconcurrency import Darwin.Mach.mach_init

It says '@preconcurrency' attribute on module 'Darwin' has no effect
When I jump to the definition of mach_task_self_ it shows me it is in Darwin > Mach > mach_init

It seems like a @preconcurrency import won't work if the thing you are trying to access is also imported by another non-preconcurrency import. Presumably, you are also importing things like Foundation.
If you put the import in a separate file,
@preconcurrency import Darwin

var machTaskSelf: mach_port_t {
    mach_task_self_
}

there is no warning.
And now you can use this computed property elsewhere.
task_info(machTaskSelf, task_flavor_t(TASK_VM_INFO), intPtr, &count)


Although this removes the warning for the @preconcurrency import, it still gives the warning that mach_task_self_ is not concurrency-safe.

Strange. It's doing it in both my main framework and a small test app I created just for this here https://file.io/LyHve5khA1bt I've also tried the new Xcode and Swift 6, but it's the same.

Doh! I was on autopilot and didn't even notice it. Thank you.

Actually, although this works in the new test project. It still gives me errors in my main Framework project. A new file has just the preconcurrency import and machTaskSelf var, but I get the error regarding pre concurrency having no effect. Could it have something do to with the order of the files compiled?

@Darren Okay, I was able to reproduce that in a SPM project (as opposed to an Xcode project). According to this, "imports from other languages are implicitly @preconcurrency", so you can just simply remove @preconcurrency. So my guess is that apparently Darwin is considered to be "from another language" in an SPM project, but not in an Xcode project.

Interesting. However removing the pre concurrency still results in the actual mach_task_self_ reporting it is not concurrency-safe.

Interestingly, removing the import Darwin altogether and just having the machTaskSelf var on its own in a file, the project compiles fine. So it must be importing it from elsewhere.

@Darren why did you unaccept? As far as I can see from your last comment, your problem is resolved. If you also want me to explain where mach_task_self_ is imported from? That is another question, and you’d need to show a [mre].

Apologies, I didn’t know I could unaccept. My problem isn’t solved. The actual project is here https://github.com/ddaddy/DJLogging-Swift and using your solution gives a compiler error when using Swift 6 which is what I’m trying to avoid.

I see the confusion. My comment about the project compiling was merely pointing out that I didn't need an import at all. It still gives the swift warning the mach_task_self_ is not concurrency-safe.

@Darren I see. I think working out why you don’t need an import for Darwin is a good first step. After you figure that out, try to make it so that you do need an import. Then doing a @preconcurrency import will probably work. That’s all I’m going to say.

Got it :) As the Framework supports objc it has a public header that imported Foundation. Removing it removed the warning. Thank you.

Worked great for me for other mach issues too:
`@preconcurrency import Darwin
var vm_kernel_page_size: vm_size_t {
Darwin.vm_kernel_page_size
}`

I ran into the same issue earlier today and ended up coming up with a workaround to get rid of the warnings.
I had to dabble a bit with Objective-C, but that allowed me to write a wrapper to mach_task_self_ that borrows Swift's actor isolation such that we can safely access the data.
I created a class with a static property that is initialized as soon as the framework is loaded and all subsequent accesses to the attribute are synchronized internally. It worked beautifully for my use case, I hope it helps you too!
MyMachTaskWrapper.h:
@import Foundation;
@import Darwin;

__attribute__((swift_attr("@MainActor")))
@interface MyMachTaskWrapper: NSObject

@property(class) mach_port_t isolatedMachTaskSelf;

@end

MyMachTaskWrapper.m:
#import "MyMachTaskWrapper.h"

@implementation MyMachTaskWrapper

static mach_port_t isolated_mach_task_self_;

// Invoked when this class is added to the Objective-C runtime
+ (void)load {
  [self setIsolatedMachTaskSelf:mach_task_self_];
}

// Just to be sure I decided to synchronize reads with a mutex lock,
// but I'm not completely sure if this is needed
+ (mach_port_t)isolatedMachTaskSelf {
  @synchronized(self) {
    return isolated_mach_task_self_;
  }
}

// This should only ever run on `load`
+ (void)setIsolatedMachTaskSelf:(mach_port_t)task {
    isolated_mach_task_self_ = task;
}

@end

Of course, you will need to expose this class to Swift. After that, the usage is as simple as:
Task { @MainActor in
  MyMachTaskWrapper.isolatedMachTaskSelf // no warnings here!
}

Note that Swift sees MyMachTaskWrapper as a @MainActor, so we must ensure we're working on the right context.
I got the idea of writing this wrapper from SE-0412, which states:

There remain tools for enforcing safety for imported global variables from other languages, such as isolating to a global actor using for example attribute((swift_attr("@MainActor"))) in C or Obj-C, or wrapping access within a safer API that declares the correct isolation or locks appropriately.

I'm still not sure if this is the best approach, but it works for me :)

Thanks. I've just tried this but I get the error "Using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported" so I think mixing objc and swift might not be the best idea here.

@Darren care to take a look at this reference?. You do have to take extra steps to make it work for framework targets, but it is possible for sure! I know because I've done it before :) You just need to figure your umbrella header and you're good to go.
